# Spring Boot Jar needs to read Keystore from classpath as File

Tags: java, file, spring-boot, classpath

In `src/main/resources` I have a folder `files`. The goal is to read the files and use them in the code below

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  ....
  File jks = null;
  try {
      final FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath*:files/prod-apicrypt.cer"));
    jks = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath*:files/mykeystore.jks");
    .....
}catch(Exception e){
//handling
}
...
```

This works in the IDE and when I do `mvn spring-boot:run` but when I create the jar and I try to run it I get `FileNotFoundException` from the .cer file. I suppose the same will happen for the keystore as well.

The problem is that I cannot just do an Inputstream and read the file line by line as I find in other replies.

I think there must be something fundamental that I am missing because Spring Boot surely has a way to read files from the classpath. I just don't know what.

Comment: Have you unpacked the jar and checked that files are actually added into jar?

Comment: First check how to read a file from inside a jar, it will solve your problem.

Comment: @Ivan yes it is in the jar. I decompiled with jd-gui and I see in BOOT-INF/classes/files/